# How to prevent user to enter data once item is selected from auto-complete result in jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery auto-complete in my application,its working fine.My requirement is once user selects item from autocomplete result/data(which we got from ajax request),if user again presses any key then already selected item must be clear in the text box,to do this which option in auto-complete I've to use ? my code goes below

```
$("#user_id").autocomplete(getUsers(), {
    multiple: false,
    matchContains: true,
    formatItem: formatItem,
    formatResult: formatResult
});
```

I'm using Jörn Zaefferer auto-complete plugin